# Can't push to firebase from android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]
[image]

I can not connect to step 2 "add real time database to your app" in get started with Realtime Databse like the picture below. Idk is that the reason why i can't push it to firebase.

When I let `system.out.prinln` in the try-catch ,but nothing is printed even tried with log but nothing print out.

```
        try {
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("foodAccount");
            myRef.setValue("heloooo");
            if (myRef == null) {
                System.out.println("faillll");
            }
            myRef.setValue("foodAccountData")
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            System.out.println("Worked");
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Not worked");
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Test"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".WorkerOrderDetailActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".WorkerOrderNoActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".WorkerMainActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LocationActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCt0I6k3QLaB3XQrNZE9uAae6kXKnoLg4M" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.gms.version"
            android:exported="true"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ProfileActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SetProfileActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SummaryActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".infoActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignInActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.test'
    compileSdk 33

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        }
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }


}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.car.ui:car-ui-lib:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `setValue()` operation, to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: To do what Alex suggested, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback

Comment: Make sure you downloaded `google-services.json` **after** you enabled Firebase Realtime Database.